# Issue starting Google Chrome on Kali Linux 2016

Tags: kali-linux

In Kali Linux 2016:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --no-sandbox --user-data-dir &
```

This it is opening Google Chrome, but I have to write this command every time I want to open Chrome.

Is there another method to access it quicker?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want an alias for this command from the command line, then putting the following line in your `~/.bashrc` file will create such an alias:

```
alias chrome="/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --no-sandbox --user-data-dir"
```

After logging out and in again, you may now type

```
$ chrome &
```

to start Google Chrome.

You should also be able to set it up as an icon that you can click to start Google Chrome through the particular command that you mention, but since I don't use Kali Linux and don't know what desktop environment they use, I can't help you with that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

run the following command, its permanent solution

```
sed -i -e 's@Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U@Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --no-sandbox@g' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```